# What is this Ruby language construct, next to method definition

Tags: ruby

Just learning Ruby at the moment and I'm also learning how Thor works so I can write a command line application. However, after looking at the examples, I can't figure out what Ruby language construct is appearing before a method definition. Looking at the following code sample ...:

```
class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"
  options :from => :required, :yell => :boolean
  def hello(name)
    output = []
    output << "from: #{options[:from]}" if options[:from]
    output << "Hello #{name}"
    output = output.join("\n")
    puts options[:yell] ? output.upcase : output
  end
end
```

... please could you tell me what 'desc' and 'options' are. I know that they provide meta data for the following method, but I don't understand the Ruby syntax. 'desc' is not an instance variable, or obviously not a method, so what is it. Once I know what it is, I can read about it. This is similar to what an attribute is in C#, where a method can be decorated with attributes which can then be inspected by reflection calls. Is this the case with 'desc' if so, what is the syntax and how are they tied to a method (in this case the method hello).

Thanks.

NB: This question is not about Thor; it's just using Thor as an example. The core of the question is the Ruby syntax itself.

Comment: Is it in fact about thor, that `desc` and `options` are methods provided by thor, and are there only because your class sub-classes Thor (`class MyCLI  < Thor`).  They are not standard ruby things, they are part of Thor. That's it.

Comment: With all due respect, this is NOT about Thor. The question is about the dynamic nature of Ruby. desc & options are properties of Thor, but that is not the point.

Answer (score 4):

The methods you mention (e.g. `desc`) form part of Thor's [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and act as convenience methods for . The method name `desc` in particular was taken wholesale from [Rake](https://github.com/rake/rake).

I'd encourage you to read the [source files for Thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/ef1eb07/lib/thor/base.rb) to understand how the DSL has been implemented.

Comment: Ok great, but it all has to be valid Ruby. I will take a deep look into Thor, but I'm still puzzled at what Ruby language construct desc and options are.

Comment: @Shantaram `desc` and `options` are nothing special. They are just method calls, without parens which are *optional* in Ruby.

Comment: Ok, I think a light bulb went off. What's confusing me is that it appears you can have code outside of a method. In a language like C#, you can't do this. All code must be inside an method, except for simple assignments (paraphrasing here just to make a point). So in this case, the text 'desc' is actually a method call (to Thor base class). The difference is when the invocation occurs. Code inside a method is clearly invoked when a client calls the method. As opposed to method calls outside of a method which is invoked when the ruby interpreter parses the source code. Is this correct?

Comment: @Shantaram Method calls even inside Class or Module definitions are not invoked during parsing phase but until during a runtime. It looks a bit confusing but due to highly dynamic nature of Ruby even class definitions can't be resolved ahead by static parsing.

Comment: Hi David, I realise now from your comment, that my last comment was a little misguided. desc & options are still only invoked at runtime. But in Ruby, we are allowed to define code outside of a method, this for me is at the heart of the issue.

Comment: @Shantaram Yep, but instead of allowed I'd rather say you are not restricted. Everything in Ruby is an expression (except keywords) and bindings are resolved during a runtime. Classes just introduce a scope inside inheritance chain and there is no reason they couldn't contain any expression. Btw. if you define a method at outer scope it becomes a private method of `Object` class.

Answer (score 4):

They are simply class method calls, here [desc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor#desc-class_method) and here is [options](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor#method_options-class_method) defined on the `Thor` class.